# Click event not working for dynamically added Li->span->id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Click event not working for dynamically added Li->span->id

```
    case"101" :   strLink = "<li style='cursor:pointer'><a data-scroll><span id=div101'>Form 101</span></a></li>"; $('.sidebar-nav').append(strLink); break;
---------------
$(".sidebar-nav").on("click", "#div101", function ()
{
      console.log("Clicked on div101");
});
```

This is Not working. How can i make it work?

Comment: Is the `.sidebar-nav` element also being added/modified dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing quote in there, which is causing the browser to misinterpret the ID:

```
case"101" :   strLink = "<li style='cursor:pointer'><a data-scroll><span id='div101'>Form 101</span></a></li>"; $('.sidebar-nav').append(strLink); break;
```

You also have to make sure to add the handler after the element has been injected into the body. If the element isn't around, it will not register the click event.

Comment: oopppsss... how bad it was!!! I spent almost 2 hrs on it.. Thank you Franker.. It was not extra.. I missed first one.. :) It is working fine now..